# Dynamic listbox populated by ADODB recordset doesn't display items when record count is 1

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, adodb

Hi I'm having a problem with a listbox.

I want to check how much people are seated (for each table) at a restaurant and also check how many are waiting to sit down. To do this I use the sheet("LunchRoom") as database and with an ADODB record set I get the results for each table.

I can't understad why if the listbox has just one record that it isn't being populated?

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i As Integer, L As Integer, T As Integer, W As Integer, H As Integer
    Dim strsql As String
    Dim ArrTables, arr, arrPax, lbx As ListBox

    Const adOpenStatic = 3
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Const adCmdText = &H1
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set LBs = New Collection

    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

    strsql = "Select IdClients, Paxname, PaxSurname from [LunchRoom$] where Table is null"
    rs.Open strsql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdUnspecified

    If rs.EOF Then lbPaxNoTable.Caption = "Noboby can be seat": GoTo PaxOnTable

    rs.MoveFirst
    arr = rs.GetRows

    With Me.LbxPaxNotSeating
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = 3
        .ColumnWidths = "0;30;30"
        .List = Application.Transpose(arr)
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With

    lbPaxNoTable.Caption = rs.RecordCount & " people wait to sit down"

    PaxOnTable:
    Set rs = Nothing

    strsql = "Select distinct Table FROM [Tables$]"
    rs.Open strsql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdUnspecified
    ReDim ArrTables(0 To rs.RecordCount)

    i = 0
    Do Until rs.EOF
        ArrTables(i) = rs![Table]
        rs.MoveNext
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Set rs = Nothing

    L = 24
    T = 150
    W = 165
    H = 94

    For i = 0 To UBound(ArrTables) - 1
        If i = 3 Then T = 252: L = 24
        strsql = "Select IdClients, Paxname, PaxSurname from [LunchRoom$] where Table = '" & ArrTables(i) & "'"
        rs.Open strsql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdUnspecified
        If rs.EOF Then arrPax = Null Else arrPax = rs.GetRows
        Call Add_Dynamic_lbx(ArrTables(i), "Forms.ListBox.1", arrPax, L, T, H, W)
        Me.Controls("lb" & ArrTables(i)).Caption = rs.RecordCount & " people are seated on " & ArrTables(i)
        L = L + 3 + W
        Set rs = Nothing
    Next i

    Dim lb As MSForms.ListBox
    Dim LMB As ListBoxDragAndDropManager
    Set LBs = New Collection

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "ListBox" Then
            Set LMB = New ListBoxDragAndDropManager
            Set LMB.ThisListBox = ctrl
            LBs.Add LMB
        End If
    Next

    fastexit:
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub

Sub Add_Dynamic_lbx(ByVal nome As String, ctr As String, val, L As Integer, T As Integer, H As Integer, W As Integer)

    Dim lbl As Control, code As String, NextLine As Long
    Set lbl = FrmPlan.Controls.Add(ctr)
    With lbl
        .name = nome
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = 3
        If Not IsNull(val) Then
            .List = Application.Transpose(val):
            .ListIndex = -1
        End If
        .Width = W
        .ColumnWidths = "0;30;150"               '1th=0 to hide the IdRst
        .Height = H
        .Left = L
        .Top = T
        .ControlTipText = nome
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Add some breakpoints and see what part of your code isn't getting executed.

Comment: @TimWilliams all code getting executed, whitout error. The laben below each listbox contain the correct no of rst, but if there are  only one rst the listbox are empty

Comment: You have `rs.Open strsql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdUnspecified` but about 8 lines above that you `Set rs = Nothing` so that should throw an error?

Comment: I open and close the rs for each table. I haven't error. 
The problem are there: arrPax = rs.GetRows
.List = Application.Transpose(val)
if rs.GetRows are only 1 row, the corrispondent listbox don't show the unique record!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `Transpose` a 2-d array returned from `GetRows`, if the "rows" dimension has only a single slot then you get back a 1-D array, not the flipped 2-D array you're expecting.

You can see this if you look at the Watch window: I ran a query returning only one row, used `GetRows` to populate `arr`, then used `Transpose` to populate `arr2` -

[image]

Notice arr2 is a single-dimension array.  Compare that with the same code and a two-record resultset below:

[image]

Instead of using `Application.Transpose` try using a VBA function like the one here: 
https://bettersolutions.com/vba/arrays/transposing.htm

Comment: thanks, I changed my code :
If rs.RecordCount > 1 Then arrPax = Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows) Else arrPax = TransposeArray(rs.GetRows)
and for popolate the listbox just  .list = arrPax.

Comment: You could make your code simpler by always using the VBA function and forget about `Application.Transpose`